# How to catch the event the button "DONE" was pressed in a webplayer under iOS 4.3?

Tags: ios4, movieplayer

Apple has changed the behavior of the movie player under WebView in iOS 4.3. When I touch "DONE" button during the playing, it just zooms out and stays on the page.
Previosly under iOS<=4.2 the player was closed with its own window.

the I'd like to catch this event and close the Controller or View with the player. Is it possible?